# Generating non-Eclipse dependent ant files

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

**SOLVED (see below)**

I have a Java project on Github and I have imported it into Eclipse Juno without problems. Generating the automatic ant files within Eclipse is also not a problem. However, when I push the build.xml to the Github repository and clone the updated repository to another machine and try to run ant, a jar is not created.

There does not seem to be a way to generate ant files **within Eclipse** that are **indpendent of Eclipse**. Is that impression correct? Do I need to manually edit the ant files?

It is a super simple project, one file defines the object type and the other one is a unit test.

```
src/main/Main.java
src/test/MainTest.java
```

The auto-generated build.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="example">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>
    <path id="example.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../usr/share/java/junit-4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
  ...... [edited]
 <target name ="makejar" description="Create a jar for the project">
    <jar jarfile="example.jar" includes="*.class" basedir="bin"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Problem solved by making a very simple ant file by hand:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="example" default="main" basedir=".">

<property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="build" />

<target name="clean">
<delete dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="makedir">
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
</javac>

</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<jar destfile="example.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
<manifest>
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="main.Main" />
</manifest>
</jar>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="compile, jar">
<description>Main target</description>
</target>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the build file please?  Also be more specific about "a jar is not created" are there errors?

Comment: And which target are you running? btw `ant -v` can work wonders for this kind of thing

Comment: After looking at what you posted there is not even a jar task in that build file, so not sure why you expect a jar to be created?

Comment: @richcoleuk sorry, i am getting frustrated, I had accidentally deleted those lines from the build file. Now at the bottom of the file. All I want is to run 'ant' (I want an executible jar at the end so that other people can easily use my program)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - looking at your build file if you just run `ant` you will get the default target `build`.

This will then invoke (based on depends):

`build-subprojects` - does nothing

`build-project` - calls `init` which copies over everything but java files in `src` to the `bin` dir and then echoes a message and then calls `javac`

No where in that does target `makejar` get called.  Have you tried issuing:

`ant`

and then

`ant makejar`

You could of course define those by making `makejar` depend on `build` in the build file like so

```
<target name ="makejar" depends="build"description="Create a jar for the project">
    <jar jarfile="example.jar" includes="*.class" basedir="bin"/>
</target>
```

But I struggle to see how this build file behaves correctly elsewhere.

Comment: so you think this is an incorrectly generated ant file? It does work within Eclipse.

Comment: When you say it "works" what do you mean?  Do you know what target is invoked from eclipse?  Have you tried my suggestions?

Comment: The generated jar file on the command line cannot be executed - executing it within eclipse works though. The error is in the manifest file (it does not contain the Main-Class element); again, within Eclipse this is not a problem. Manually defining the main class does not help.